# How to stop android studio from stepping into android library files?

Tags: android

How can I stop android studio going to library classes that I have no interest in debugging? It keeps stepping into library files that I don't have problems with. I only want to step within my project source code.

Is there a way to blacklist files that are no interest to me? Can't seem to find that option in the AS preferences.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Preferences -> Build... -> Debugger -> Stepping

Don't know if it does exactly what you want, but it's what we've got.

Comment: This is exactly want I want. Just like blacklisting files I don't need when you debug in Chrome. Something to that level. But this would do! Thanks!